# how to change URL in consumed WCF service - .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wcf

I have consumed WCF service in .net core application. But old URL I used is not working anymore and we have new URL. I tried changing new URL in ConnectedService.json & Reference.cs file but getting System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException.
I also tried consumed service again with new URL but it is secured(https) so I was unable to consume it.
Is there any way I can change code and configure new URL?

ConnectedService.json

```html
{
  "ProviderId": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedService.Wcf",
  "Version": "15.0.40203.910",
  "GettingStartedDocument": {
    "Uri": "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=858517"
  },
  "ExtendedData": {
    "inputs": [
      "http://quote-engineapp.net/Package/MarketingSoftware.svc"
    ],
    "collectionTypes": [
      "System.Array",
      "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2"
    ],
    "namespaceMappings": [
      "*,EngineService"
    ]
     ........
    }
 }
```

Reference.cs

```html
private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
        {
            if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IMarketingSoftware))
            {
                return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://quote-engineapp.net/Package/MarketingSoftware.svc");
            }
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
        }
```

```html
New url : https://uat.cloud.api.ppl3.com/rapid//quote/v1
```

Comment: The best solution is to re-add a service reference based on the new URL.